# Convert List of String to a String separated by a delimiter

Tags: vb.net, string

Whats the best way to convert a list(of string) to a string with the values seperated by a comma (`,`)

Comment: Why not turn this into a speed / performance question?  "What is the FASTEST way to..."

Comment: Can't best be interprited as Fastest AND/OR Efficient ?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```
String.Join(",", myListOfStrings.ToArray())
```

Comment: The only thing I might add is a null/empty check before the `ToArray()` conversion: `myListOfStrings.Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray()`

Comment: Great piece of code, thank you! Just another tip for Windows Workflow Foundation / UiPath users, you can put this code into a workflow and as an alternative to @Cory's above code, to ignore blank lists, just put 'True' in the Invoke Workflow File activity's 'ContinueOnError' property.

Comment: There is no need really to convert it `ToArray()`. You can use it as is. `String.Join(",", myListOfStrings)`

Comment: I was using a standard loop to combine a large list to a string and it was taking about 12 seconds.  This took less then 1.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by "best". The least memory intensive is to first calculate the size of the final string, then create a StringBuilder with that capacity and add the strings to it.

The StringBuilder will create a string buffer with the correct size, and that buffer is what you get from the ToString method as a string. This means that there are no extra intermediate strings or arrays created.

```
// specify the separator
string separator = ", ";

// calculate the final length
int len = separator.Length * (list.Count - 1);
foreach (string s in list) len += s.Length;

// put the strings in a StringBuilder
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(len);
builder.Append(list[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++) {
   builder.Append(separator).Append(list[i]);
}

// get the internal buffer as a string
string result = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: No matter what you mean by "best" this is probably not the best.

Comment: @mquander: It's the least memory intensive, I clearly stated that in the first paragraph. If you need to keep the memory load down, this is clearly the best method.

Comment: Not much difference in terms of memory intensiveness. There is no intermediate string in Join method. It's just the array of references.

Comment: Profiling would give us the answer but I doubt there's a big enough difference to justify using this code instead of the one line String.Join.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
string = ["a","2"]\n
newstring = ""
endOfString = len(string)-1
for item in string:
    newstring = newstring + item
if item != string[endOfString]:
    newstring = newstring ","'
```

Comment: Pseudocode is sometimes nice but actual language implementations are preferred here.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
dim str as string = ""
for each item as string in lst
  str += ("," & item)
next
return str.substring(1)
```

It takes off the first char from the string `(",")`